# How do I answer questions asking for chance in probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If it is known that the password is one of the 3,300,000 entries in a list of
>   words and proper names, and again the hacker tries 2,000,000 random
>   attempts to crack it. What’s the chance of his success?

password is 8 digit and can be from a-z.

How do I solve it? i get very confused.

Comment: One of the $3,300,000$ is the password.  What is the chance the password is among the $2,000,000$ tried?  The details of the password do not matter at all because we are given the list.

Comment: so its 3,300,000 C 1 / 2,000,000 ? @RossMillikan

Comment: No, that is greater than $1$.  Think about it in small numbers.  You have ten objects and paint one red.  Now somebody closes their eyes and picks three at random.  What is the chance the red one is picked?

Comment: im sorry i really am trying. 1/10 * 9/10 * 8/10* 3! ? @RossMillikan

Comment: It is just as simple as $3/10$.  That is the fraction of the objects selected.

Comment: why do i keep getting confused? @rossMillikan

Comment: so the answer is 2,000,000/3,300,000 ?

Comment: I think because you are thinking about formulas, not about the situation, but I can't be sure.

Comment: isn't it just 1/2,000,000 ? @RossMillikan I don't understand

Comment: There are $2,000,000$ passwords tried and $1,300,000$ not tried.  The chance the right one is tried is then $2,000,000/3,300,000$ and the chance it is not is $1,300,000/3,300,000$